# Calculation of daily average of soil water potential from 15-minutely based data

Tags: r, datetime

I'm new in R. I have a data frame of soil water potential values that were recorded in two areas and 5 depth with 15-minute intervals. I would like to calculate the daily average of soil water potential for two years in each area and depth. Would you please help me?

Here is a part of the data frame:

```
TimeStamp_Field       Area     Parameter           Value     Sensor_UID    Depth Unit
07/01/2017  00:00:00    S   soil_water_potential    1.2     N_B3_TM_10/1_WP 10  pF
07/01/2017  00:15:00    S   soil_water_potential    1.193   N_B3_TM_10/1_WP 10  pF
07/01/2017  00:29:52    S   soil_water_potential    1.204   N_B3_TM_10/1_WP 10  pF
07/01/2017  00:45:00    S   soil_water_potential    1.203   N_B3_TM_10/1_WP 10  pF
07/01/2017  01:00:00    S   soil_water_potential    1.205   N_B3_TM_10/1_WP 10  pF
07/01/2017  01:15:00    S   soil_water_potential    1.214   N_B3_TM_10/1_WP 10  pF
07/01/2017  01:30:00    S   soil_water_potential    1.22    N_B3_TM_10/1_WP 10  pF
07/01/2017  01:45:00    S   soil_water_potential    1.219   N_B3_TM_10/1_WP 10  pF
07/01/2017  02:00:00    S   soil_water_potential    1.222   N_B3_TM_10/1_WP 10  pF
07/01/2017  02:15:00    S   soil_water_potential    1.229   N_B3_TM_10/1_WP 10  pF
07/01/2017  02:30:00    S   soil_water_potential    1.233   N_B3_TM_10/1_WP 10  pF
07/01/2017  02:45:00    S   soil_water_potential    1.231   N_B3_TM_10/1_WP 10  pF
07/01/2017  03:00:00    S   soil_water_potential    1.23    N_B3_TM_10/1_WP 10  pF
07/01/2017  03:15:00    S   soil_water_potential    1.239   N_B3_TM_10/1_WP 10  pF
07/01/2017  03:30:00    S   soil_water_potential    1.238   N_B3_TM_10/1_WP 10  pF
07/01/2017  03:45:00    S   soil_water_potential    1.236   N_B3_TM_10/1_WP 10  pF
07/01/2017  04:00:00    S   soil_water_potential    1.24    N_B3_TM_10/1_WP 10  pF
```

Comment: What have you tried so far, could you set out the code you have tried and explain where your coding problems are?

Answer (score 0):

You can create new fields for the day/month/year out of your timestamp, and then `group_by` and `summarise` over these columns + parameter/sensor_UID (if needed) to compute averages.